# Voronoi diagrams applications where the input order has some known properties?

Tags: delaunay-triangulation, voronoi

Are there applications of [Voronoi diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) or [Delaunay triangulations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) where the order in which the points are generated (and given to the algorithm) have some known properties (e.g. concatenation of points belonging to distinct entities, such as when a data set is the union of several pre-existing data sets)?

More specifically:

- [Snoeyink and van Kreveld](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.41.4826) showed that the Delaunay triangulation could be encoded in a "good" order of the points, in such a way that it could be reconstructed in linear time from the coordinates given in this order (and many equivalent orders).
- Many other algorithms are known to compute the Voronoi diagram in linear time if the points are "randomly distributed".
- I am wondering if in some practical applications, the order in which the points are generated is close to those "good" orders (as in, the concatenation or shuffling of several subsequences in a "good" order).

Comment: I thought astronomy would be one such application, but the astronomer to whom I asked said that the order is the result of a human process, and that no guaranty can be given on any property of this order, because the (human) process producing this order might be different for each instance.